Matrix-like action in a movie about a fraternity
I was in Sweden for the last couple of days and saw the start of a movie. It intrigued me but I never found out the name of the movie. At first I thought it was called "The Fraternity" based on those words being said at the beginning of the movie. However, it turned out that is not its title.
Please can someone help me identify it, as I was not able to view it for more than the first couple of minutes, while in Stockholm and would like to see it whole sometime.
----SPOILER ALERT---
I think the movie is narrated by the main character who is a young guy working in an office. He's all sweaty and takes pills, presumably, for that condition.
Right near the beginning of the movie a man walks into an office. There's a startled woman (secretary?) sitting at a desk. He tells her not to worry and that she would already have been dead if there was anything to worry about (or something along those lines). Assuming that all is clear he walks out again but gets a bullet through the head. Then in some reverse-Matrix-like scene we see the bullet ... move back through his head ... all the way back into the rifle it came from on one of the rooftops across the street. Its a very fancy bullet that unscrews in-flight and has very elaborate markings as far as I can remember. 
The man (yes he's still/again alive) uses his binocular vision to spot the assassin, runs along the corridor and jumps to the other building shooting the assassin and several other people on the roof in mid-air. 
They all seem to be part of a secret fraternity.

Seems to be Wanted (in the first scenes): http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0493464/?ref_=nv_sr_2 with the scene here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lf3MqrE07I4

@Larme You're absolutely right! Just watched the trailer on IMDB and that's the one. Please add this as an answer so I can appove it.

I think you're looking for Wanted starring, James McAvoy, Angelina Jolie, Morgan Freeman, and Thomas Kretschmann.
The scene can be seen here:




This movie is called Wanted. The matrix like scene is one of the opening scenes to the movie, and the main character stats out sweaty and takes pills for a condition. He later learns about a secret fraternity of assassins, and learns that his condition is actually his ability to speed up his heart rate to boost his reaction and perception to superhuman levels.

You're absolutely correct. However, I can only accept one answer and @Larme beat you to it in the comments section. +1 nevertheless.
